# system format exception in string.format

Tags: c#, jquery, html, xmlwriter, string.format

I have an http server written in c# and I write some of the html in c#.
I have problems with the quotes in writing some jQuery using XmlWiter.

this one works

```
xmlWriter.WriteRaw(@" $(document).ready(function (){  $("".fill-div"").attr(""href"",""Photo by Kelly Clark"");});");
```

But this one doesnt and its what I want to do

```
xmlWriter.WriteRaw(string.Format(@" $(document).ready(function (){  $("".fill-div"").attr(""href"",""{0}"");});", backUrl));
```

backUrl is a local variable which I get in my c# function and I need to set it as a link

Comment: "doesn't work" means what?

Comment: thanks. please see the question title again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error occurs because the first parameter of your `string.Format` already has curly braces to denote the function. You must escape the braces similar to what you did to the quotes:

```
xmlWriter.WriteRaw(string.Format(@" $(document).ready(function (){{  $("".fill-div"").attr(""href"",""{0}"");}});", backUrl));
```